# How to split data.frame into smaller data.frames of predetermined number of rows?

Tags: r, split, dataframe

I have the following data frame:

```
 df <- data.frame(a=rep(1:3),b=rep(1:3),c=rep(4:6),d=rep(4:6))
    df
      a b c d
    1 1 1 4 4
    2 2 2 5 5
    3 3 3 6 6
```

i would like to have a vector N which determines my window size so for thsi example i will set

```
N <- 1
```

I would like to split this dataframe into equal portions of N rows and store the 3 resulting dataframes into a list.

I have the following code:

```
groupMaker <- function(x, y) 0:(x-1) %/% y

testlist2 <- split(df, groupMaker(nrow(df), N))
```

The problem is that this code renames my column names by adding an `X0.` in front

```
result <- as.data.frame(testlist2[1])

result
    X0.a X0.b X0.c X0.d
1    1    1    4    4
>
```

I would like a code that does the exact same thing but keeps the column names as they are. please keep in mind that my original data has a lot more than 3 rows so i need something that is applicable to a much larger dataframe.

Comment: You need `[[` i.e. `as.data.frame(testlist2[[1]])` . BTW, you can also use `gl` i.e. `split(df, as.numeric(gl(nrow(df), N, nrow(df))))`

Comment: silly me. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extract a `list` element, we can use `[[`.  Also, as each `list` elements are `data.frame`s, we don't need to explicitly call `as.data.frame` again.

```
testlist2[[1]]
```

We can also use `gl` to create the grouping variable.

```
split(df, as.numeric(gl(nrow(df), N, nrow(df))))
```